# Не срабатывает обработчик

Tags: android, java

Всем привет! Есть такая проблема. Написал по тесту прогу, которая при изменении seek bar меняет кнопки. Но есть ошибка. Выкладываю интересующий код.

```
sBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1); - создают объект sBar
```

Ниже создаю интерфейс обработчика.

```
OnSeekBarChangeListener SeekBarChange = new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
            @Override
              public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                  boolean fromUser) {
Сдесь какой-то код
}
```

Ниже привязываю обработчки к seekBar.

```
sBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(SeekBarChange);
```

Пишет следующую ошибку:

**SeekBarChange cannot be resolved to a variable**

Почему? Вроде бы все правильно сделал. Где ошибка, ребята?

Comment: вы 100%  объявляете SeekBarChange в одном блоке, а пытаетесь использовать в другом. Следовательно, прежде, чем начать изучать программирование для Андроид, надо изучить основы JAVA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вероятно проблема с областью видимости, но по предоставленным фрагментам кода точно ничего сказать нельзя